# Walnut leaves in compost - yes or no?

Tags: leaves, compost, walnut

I have several walnut trees in my yard, and this year I am going to make compost for the first time in my life, and would like to know whether I should include walnut leaves in my compost pile.

There are contradictory opinions on this matter on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can - if your trees are black walnut, the leaves will have a higher content of juglone, but it will break down as it composts over time and won't be an issue. The juglone disappears quicker if you shred the leaves prior to composting, so maybe run the mower over them first if you can. https://laidbackgardener.blog/2015/10/15/yes-you-can-compost-black-walnut-leaves/

If you have lots of leaves, its better to compost them separately rather than just piling them all in the compost heap, This Q and A might be of interest regarding that [What is the best way to compost a large pile of leaves with minimal effort?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/29932/what-is-the-best-way-to-compost-a-large-pile-of-leaves-with-minimal-effort?rq=1)

Comment: Different opinion here: https://bluems.wordpress.com/2016/07/03/black-walnut-tolerant-ornamentals/ "Because of their juglone content, composted black walnut leaves should not be used around non-black walnut tolerant plants." ... How to know what the most truthful fact is?

Comment: yes, well, I'd go for Ohio State University information in the link I provided initially, that's why I chose that one - you can find lots of conflicting information and misinformation all over the internet - the trick is to check the source its come from.if the source is horticultural (ie RHS or similar bodies) or a university research or horticultural department, that's the one you believe.

Comment: I don't see any link to Ohio University, you posted only link to a private blog. @Bamboo